# Vyatta Router order not honoring VLAN id's

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Ordering a Vyatta router on #SoftLayer #BlueMix and the order JSON is the following

```
gatewayOrder = {
    'orderContainers': [{
        'quantity': 2,  # high availability is 2 quantity
        'hardware': [
            {
            'hostname': vyatta_fr_hostname,
            'domain': vyatta_domain,
            'networkVlans': [
                {'vlanNumber': vlanPub },
                {'vlanNumber': vlanPriv }
            ]},
            {
                'hostname': vyatta_bu_hostname,
                'domain': vyatta_domain,
                'networkVlans': [
                    {'vlanNumber': vlanPub },
                    {'vlanNumber': vlanPriv }
            ]}
        ],
        'location': locationId,
        'packageId': pkgIdGW,
        'prices': [
            {'id': vyatta_system_dual_intel_2620 },
            {'id': vyatta_os_vyatta_5600 },
            {'id': vyatta_64_gb_ram },
            {'id': vyatta_disk_controller },
            {'id': vyatta_disk_500_gb },
            {'id': vyatta_disk_4_tb },
            {'id': vyatta_net_20000 },
            {'id': vyatta_net_10_gbps },
            {'id': vyatta_kvm_reboot },
            {'id': vyatta_ssl_vpn },
            {'id': vyatta_1_ip },
            {'id': vyatta_redundant_power },
            {'id': vyatta_host_monitoring },
            {'id': vyatta_auto_reboot },
            {'id': vyatta_notification_email },
            {'id': vyatta_nessus },
        ],
    }]
}
```

Vlans are not being added to the order.  Why?

Comment: ¿What is the error or the exception thrown?

Comment: There is no error. The order goes through fine. VLAN info does not show up in the order when the SL engineer gets it. As confirmed by SL support

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

Try the following rest example:

```
method: POST
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder


JSON body:

{
"parameters": [
   {
    "orderContainers": [
     {
      "hardware": [
        {
          "hostname": "vyattaVlantest",
          "domain": "domain.com",
          "primaryBackendNetworkComponent":{
                "networkVlanId":1111111
                },
          "primaryNetworkComponent":{
                "networkVlanId":2222222
                }
        }
      ],
      "location":"DALLAS13" ,
      "packageId": 236,
      "quantity": 1,
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 177611
        },
        {
          "id": 17182
        },
        {
          "id": 201189
        },
        {
          "id": 876
        },
        {
          "id": 14031
        },
        {
          "id": 342
        },
        {
          "id": 273
        },
        {
          "id": 792
        },
        {
          "id": 55
        },
        {
          "id": 58
        },
        {
          "id": 420
        },
        {
          "id": 418
        },
        {
          "id": 21
        },
        {
          "id": 57
        },
        {
          "id": 906
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

The returned value in the response should display something like what´s below:

```
                    "primaryBackendNetworkComponent": {
                        "networkVlanId": 1111111,
                        "networkVlan": {
                            "id": 1111111,
                            "primarySubnetId": 123123123,
                            "vlanNumber": 591
                        }
                    },
                    "primaryNetworkComponent": {
                        "networkVlanId": 2222222,
                        "networkVlan": {
                            "id": 2222222,
                            "primarySubnetId": 789789789,
                            "vlanNumber": 768
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
```

Comment: I dont even see a place in the order verification that indicates a VLAN can be given in the order.

Comment: I updated the answer, change the proper values for yours, it should display the proper vlan information as above in the returned response

Comment: This did not work.  Now the api is complaining that the VLAN is not standard

Comment: I dont know how to add information to this question to show you the error.

Comment: /SoftLayer/API.py", line 358, in call
    return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer-5.4.2-py2.7.egg/SoftLayer/API.py", line 261, in call
    return self.transport(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer-5.4.2-py2.7.egg/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 215, in __call__
    raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): The backend VLAN #2266303 is not a standard VLAN

Comment: That error is due that you are trying to use a Transit type Vlan instead of an standard in the order, try the following to obtain the available public and private vlans for your order:
method POST
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/getVlans
JSON body
{
 "parameters":[
 957095, 236
 ]
}
Change the locationId and the package for the ones you are using in the order container.

Comment: the two vlans i am connecting this to is the 764 for the public interface and 819 for the private interface.  these are the gateway vlans.  I am not looking to add associated vlans at the time of creation.  I have created several routers with these VLANS using the UI.

Comment: I ran the API command - it comes back with 949 and 996 for dal9 pod6.  These are the correct ASSOCIATED vlans.  But they are NOT the correct Gatway vlans that the router needs to be placed on.  As I commented above, I need these routers on 764 and 819.  Just as I would order through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

> This did not work. Now the api is complaining that the VLAN is not standard

You specified the VLAN id correctly, but didn't pick a correct VLAN. You can only order Vyattas on Standard vlans, which is to say VLANs that are not already part of a gateway as either a gateway or associated vlans.

The control portal order page should reflect this as well.

Comment: Vlan 764 and 819 are Dal9 pod6 and can service any number of routers.  I have ordered 8 routers over the past 2 months and they have all been assigned to these two vlans.  All at the same time.  I am not referring to "associated vlans" - I am aware that associated vlans are 1:1 with a router pair and cannot be shared.  I just tested the creation of a router pair with the portal and it also DOES NOT include the gateway vlans, a technician must fill those in.

Comment: It would appear to me that the API does NOT support the assignment of "gateway vlans."  This requires manual intervention.  It does support the assignment of "associated vlans" and we are aware of how that works.  I am able to add them after provision without a problem.